# Receiving processes through TCPClient with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, listview, tcp, tcpclient, networkstream

I have been attempting a TCP client/server program and have been playing around with GetProcesses. I am able to get the full list of processes on the client side, however it only lists one process per call.

I added a log to see what was happening and I actually am getting all the data. Maybe my issue is when I split up the data on the client side..

If you are familiar with TCPClient, or just know where I am going wrong, id greatly appreciate your input as I have only been writing in VB for a few months now and I feel quite annoyed. lol

Thanks

Id post the image here but I need more reputation.. Here is the link
https://i.ibb.co/7rS8bRY/listproc-issue.png

Client code:

```
Dim ns As NetworkStream = clientOne.GetStream()
Dim gs(clientOne.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
ns.Read(gs, 0, CInt(clientOne.ReceiveBufferSize))
Dim rs As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(gs)
Dim id() As String = Split(rs, "*", -1, CompareMethod.Text)
Dim tri As String = id(1)

        If id(0) = 14 Then
            Try
                Dim idsa As Integer = tri.IndexOf("@")
                Dim fdsa As String = tri.Substring(idsa + 1, tri.IndexOf("&", idsa + 1) - idsa - 1)
                Dim idsb As Integer = tri.IndexOf("%")
                Dim fdsb As String = tri.Substring(idsb + 1, tri.IndexOf("#", idsb + 1) - idsb - 1)
                Dim idsc As Integer = tri.IndexOf("!")
                Dim fdsc As String = tri.Substring(idsc + 1, tri.IndexOf("$", idsc + 1) - idsc - 1)
                LVProc.Items.Add(New ListViewItem({fdsa, fdsb, fdsc}))
                TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + vbNewLine + "Process added to list" + vbNewLine
                LVProc.Refresh()
            Catch
            End Try
        End If
        If id(0) = 13 Then
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + vbNewLine + "Unable to list Process" + vbNewLine
        End If
```

Server code:

```
                 If id(0) = 10 Then
                    Try
                        For Each findp As Process In Process.GetProcesses()
                            If findp.MainWindowTitle = "" Then
                            Else
                                Dim msgRespa As String = "14*" + "@" + findp.Id.ToString + "&%" + findp.ProcessName + "#!" + findp.MainWindowTitle + "$"
                                Dim msgSenda As [Byte]() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msgRespa)
                                ns.Write(msgSenda, 0, msgSenda.Length)
                            End If
                        Next findp
                    Catch
                        Dim msgResp As String = "13*"
                        Dim msgSend As [Byte]() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msgResp)
                        ns.Write(msgSend, 0, msgSend.Length)
                    End Try
                 End If
```

Comment: (I'll leave picking on the extensive use of legacy vb adapter functions and fast-n-loose typing/comapring strings with ints for another time)

Comment: Aside from the slightly wobbly logic of your client side read potentially not reading as much as the server side sent (what if the server sends 1000 bytes and your ReceiveBufferSize is 500?), can why did you use a loop on the server side to prepare some repetitive string like `14*@1&%notepad#!untitled$14*@2&%word#!Document1$` but then on the client side you split it on some repeated character `*` but you then didn't use a loop to process the split results? Why only parse the first process in the array that arose from the split? Why no `id(2)` etc? Also, splitting on `*` is broken; `14` repeats

Comment: Haha thanks for not going too hard on me guys.. For the server side, correct me if i am wrong, but I wont be able to create a string in ForEach because ns.write tries to send to stream every time it finds a process.. so even if i create a string, I feel it wouldnt help.. My client side code is pretty noobish I imagine, When I tried to create a loop in the past, it froze my form..

Comment: Okay I was wrong, I created a string in the server and the response is the full list of Processes. (like the 2nd click in the picture) Now I will have to split up every set between each 14*. Seems a bit more difficult but do-able..

Comment: ugh i suck. lol. my results are now like 
@22392&%AWCC#!Alienware Command Center$

@22392&%AWCC#!Alienware Command Center$

@22392&%AWCC#!Alienware Command Center$


I am having a difficult time splitting all of that up. even with baby steps. I tried counting how many sets of data is between each * and $ and then writing each to a new line with a loop but have failed miserably.. Can someone give me a pointer when it comes to counting and splitting this data?

Comment: Is there some reason you're using this wacky string? "Normal people" ;) would just make an ASPNETCore API project, and have a controller method like `Function Index() as ActionResult` `Return Json(Processes.GetProcesses())` `End Function` and then on the client side they'd just download the string and jsonparse it, or maybe even enable swagger on the server and use something like AutoRest to write all the client code